# Angular 2 access component variable from service, that is bound to another service, which is bound to component

Tags: variables, service, angular, components

Question is simple: how do I access variable from a service without passing down that components variable through function itself?

I don't want to pass it through function, because I want to access the variable located in `AppComponent` called `thingies` from `tabs.service` **BUT** called from `sitetree.service`. Function `f_in_sitetreeService` is gona be called somewhere at some time, dynamically (in plunker I call it from appcomponent, but in reality it will be from another place).

In other words, I have a service which is calling another service function, which in turn accesses it's components variable.

What I want:

In `tabs.service` I commented out 2 lines, which pushes a new thingy, and then logs the array. Commented them out because I don't know how to correctly declare/access that components array there, and that's what I need to know.

Plunker:
http://plnkr.co/edit/rFSW1UXz7Gw1rMXlD2Md?p=preview

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'm not sure I understand your question, but I'll try answering...

It sounds like you want TabsService to manipulate a property defined on some component (in your example, the AppComponent).  First comment: this is likely not a good approach.  Normally services should own application data, not components.

However, if you really need/want to do that, you have to somehow pass a reference to the array to your service, say in ngOnInit in the AppComponent:

```
ngOnInit() {
   this.tabsService.setArrayReference(this.thingies);
}
```

Then in TabsService:

```
setArrayReference(ref) { this.thingies = ref; }
```

Since we're dealing with a JavaScript reference type, both the AppComponent and the TabsService will now both reference the same/one array.

Now you can access and manipulate the array from the AppComponent and the TabsService.

[Updated plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/EiipLmOXhx5lkDzpuNAX?p=preview).

Comment: Holy snippets! I had no idea of such a function, and it works like a charm, thank you!!! And I will also take into account what you said, about moving data to service :)